# Raven backup on windows server 2003

Tags: ravendb

Has anyone got Raven backup/restore working on Server 2003? I am using 1.0.616.0 of Raven.backup.exe to backup and Raven.Server.exe to restore.

Problem is the restore seems to corrupt Raven so it won't start.

There's an open query with ManagedEsent on codeplex: http://managedesent.codeplex.com/discussions/405020

If I get a response then I'll post back here with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible at the moment, however future versions of Raven backup may support Server 2003.

For the present we are just going with a volume snapshot-based solution which is only temporary as we'll be rolling onto Server 2008R2/2012 very soon.